# How to use JavaCompiler from tools.jar without JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, javacompiler, tools.jar

I am trying to create an application that can compile a provided `.java` file during runtime. I understand that there is a programmatical compiler available within the `tools.jar` of the JDK. However, I cannot guarantee that the user of the application has JDK. I have attempted to package `tools.jar` within the application and reference it as a library. This seems to work within the Eclipse IDE when I have `tools.jar` added into the Bootstrap Entries of the classpath. When exporting the application to a runnable jar (with `tools.jar` packaged with it), 
`ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();` returns `null`. I am not exactly sure what the issue is, but I believe it may have to do with the Bootstrap Entries of the classpath not being properly preserved when the application is exported to a runnable jar. Any ideas? Are there any alternatives to the `tools.jar` compiler that I could use? Thanks for your patience, as this is my first question posted here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the compiler within "tools.jar"

```
ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()
```

will return the compiler from the jdk defined in the path variable,
you can do this instead:

```
File file = new File(pathToToolsJar);
URL[] urls = new URL[]{ file.toURI().toURL() };
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class compilerClass = loader.loadClass("com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool");
JavaCompiler compiler = (JavaCompiler) compilerClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Or you can add tools.jar as a library at compile time

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool;
...
JavaCompiler compiler = new JavacTool();
```

Or you can change System properties, but that leads to unexpected behaviors

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. This seems to work perfectly. Any chance I could get a brief explanation as to what the alternative is doing?

Comment: Uhm, I'm not really sure why I suggested to use reflection, you could just add tools.jar as a library and instance it the old way

`import com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool;`

`JavaCompiler compiler = new JavacTool();`

Comment: What I suggested originaly was to load tools.jar at runtime using reflection; Using URLClassLoader is an easy way to load dependencies at runtime, you just ask the loader for the class you want, and it looks in the urls you specified for the class